# When the user's timezone is known, can the bot framework handle yesterday/tomorrow correctly?

Tags: botframework

In some cases, the bot may have knowledge of the user's timezone. Is there a way to pass this knowledge to the bot framework so that it can handle certain date forms correctly - e.g. "tomorrow" & "yesterday"? Even things like "next friday" are sometimes sensitive to the timezone.

Currently, it appears that these are handled assuming the user's timezone offset is zero.

Comment: is your question about how LUIS recognizes built-in dates and time?

Comment: No, there's code in the bot framework, apart from LUIS, that uses Chronic to parse date/time entities. The problem is that there isn't a way to tell the bot framework to tell Chronic about the user's timezone (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Could you give an example of the code? As far as I know this is done by LUIS, so some code may clarify things.

Comment: The framework sometimes does this parsing itself, as in https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/07f3e894fd15f96c124f89953e491aa2d150090a/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/Recognize.cs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the chronic parser is unreachable so you can't really change anything to that. I see 3 solutions.

Solution 1: Create your own `RecognizeDateTime` class to work with utc time or however you want.

Solutions 2: When you get the date (in the validation method for example) add the utc offset to the time. This will preserve the right date, for utc times and local times.

```
dateTime += TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(dateTime);
```

solution 3: When the datetime is created by using a string like "yesterday", the day is correct but the time defaults to 00:00 or 12AM. To make this less sensitive you can just add 12 hours to the UTC time. This will preserve the day in almost all timezones. (All timezones above 12+ will have a problem. Luckily there aren't many people there.) (This is the solution I'm currently using for one of my solutions)

Comment: Thanks - I did something along these lines as a workaround. When intents are invoked that use datetime entities, I just parse them again with a Chronic parser configured for the correct timezone. There should really be a better way, but this will work.